# Words in common (Python)

Tags: python

So I've been having a lot of trouble with this problem. I have to find the words in common from an English.txt and a French.txt.

english.txt:

```
circle
table
year
competition
```

french.txt:

```
bien
competition
merci
air
table
```

My desired output:

```
competition
table
```

However, when I did my code I didn't include french text but got:
competition

table

This is my code:

```
filenameI = "english.txt"
file = open(filenameI, "r")
for line in file:
   print(line)
```

Comment: How do you plan to compare with the French list?

Comment: Your code just reads and prints the `english.txt` - I don't see how you are getting the output described.

Comment: @openwonk yeah but I don't know how to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filenameI) as I:
    contentI = I.read().splitlines()

with open(filenameF) as F:
    contentF = F.read().splitlines()
```

Then go ahead and loop through contentF and contentI and compare the two, printing when they match

```
for i in contentI:
    for f in contentf:
        if i == f:
          print(i)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This won't find matches for words that aren't in the same position in both files (look at "competition" in OP's examples).

Comment: Yes it will, it loops over the first set while looping over the whole of the second set for each of the first

Comment: nested for loops

Comment: D'oh! You're right. I'm on a roll with stupidity tonight. I guess I should go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filenameI = "english.txt"
filename2 = "french.txt"
file = open(filenameI, "r")
file2 = open(filenameI, "r")

list1 = [line for line in file]
list2 = [line for line in file2]

out = set(list1) - (set(list1) - set(list2))
```

Note that it is better to open file using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this worked out for you or not!

```
e_words = set(line.strip() for line in open("english.txt")) # speck of sanity check here
f_words = set(line.strip() for line in open("french.txt"))

print e_words & f_words
# please iterate this and do whatevs..
```

## EDIT 1 (BEING CONCISE IS A GOOD THING BUT THIS TIME NO DANGLING FILE HANDLERS)

```
output = None
with open("english.txt") as e, open("french.txt") as f:
     output = set([line.strip() for line in e.readlines()]) & set([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])
print output
```

Comment: There is such a thing as too concise. You should be closing your file handles (or using `with`), especially in answers directed at inexperienced programmers. Not closing them is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @d-coder sadly it didn't work, the output just shows: set()

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)as it will give you an intersection between two collections.

Also use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to handle closing the file automatically.

```
with open('english.txt') as eng, open('french.txt') as fr:
    print(set(x.strip() for x in eng).intersection(x.strip() for x in set(fr)))
```

Output:

```
{'table', 'competition'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file1 = open("english.txt", "rb+")
file2 = open("french.txt", "rb+")

list1 = [line for line in file1]
list2 = [line for line in file2]

common1 = (set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
e = set(open("english.txt"))
f = set(open("french.txt"))
for c in e & f:
print(c, end="")
```

I just make two sets out of the two texts. Then use a loop where for every common word (using "e & f") it lists them out on each line.

p.s.

```
end=""
```

just makes sure there isn't an extra line between each word.